# Javascript regexp infinite loop related to uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, v8

I've created a regexp in node.js able to match parts of text that look like an URL. However, on some text, my regexp creates an infinite loop!

The whole regexp is:

```
/(((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+-?)+\.[a-z\d/\-._~:?#@!$&'*+,;=`]+)/gi
```

But after some debug, I found that the infinite loop is caused only by this part: `/((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+-?)+\./gi`

```
> let r = /((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+-?)+\./gi
> const txt = "www.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_~:/?#@!$&'*+,;=`"
> r.test(txt)
^CError: Script execution interrupted. // infinite loop
```

I've done more tests to understand the problem. First, without flags:

```
> r = /((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+-?)+\./
> r.test(txt)
true
```

Surprisingly, it works!
Test 2 with only `g` flag:

```
> r = /((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+-?)+\./g
> r.test(txt)
true
```

Works too!
Test 3 with only `i` flag:

```
> r = /((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+-?)+\./i
> r.test(txt)
^CError: Script execution interrupted. // infinite loop
```

Failure... So I decided to remove `i` flag and use A-Z instead:

```
> r = /((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-zA-Z\d]+-?)+\./
> r.test(txt)
^CError: Script execution interrupted. // infinite loop
```

Not working... Does someone understand the problem ? Is there a solution ?

Comment: Yes, it is another case of catastrophic backtracking. Not sure what exact input you need to match and which to fail, but try `/((ftp|https?):\/\/|www\.)?[a-z\d]+(?:-[a-z\d]+)*\./i`

Comment: Yes, not really "infinite"

Comment: @DenysSéguret This regExp is used on random generated text and I had to stop my script after 15 minutes because it didn't want to stop. So It might be infinite...

Comment: @JérémyPouyet It's more probably an exponential function of the input length.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/nppM46/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a catastrophic backtracking.

To avoid this phenomenon, try to build a regex that would always progress from left to right (i.e. a failure to match would stop the regex, not make it try some sub part elsewhere). Said otherwise: there shouldn't be several ways to match a part of your string (or the regex engine will try them all, which can, in some case, lead to an exponentially sized tree of possibilities).

Trying to understand your real goal, I can propose this solution:

```
/((ftp|https?):\/\/|(www\.))?([a-z\d]+)(-[a-z\d]+)*\./gi
```

(which is also probably more correct)

Another solution would be to use a non backtracking regex engine such as [R2](https://github.com/google/re2/) (yes there is a binding for node). In my experience R2 in node is slower than the standard regex engine so it only makes sense when you have user inputted regexes as you most often can find a non catastrophic regex when you're the regex author.

Comment: *try to build a regex that would always progress from left to right* - that is what the regex engine does by default :) The real reason is the optional subpattern inside a quantified group and its location in the whole pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not exactly in this case: when there are several ways to match a subgroup, it has to try a tree of possibilities, which in practice means it tries, then goes back for another try.

Comment: I'd use a term "linear matching". When you say "build a regex that would always progress from left to right", it sounds ambiguous.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree it's ambiguous. If you feel like you have a better wording, please edit

Comment: Maybe *To avoid this phenomenon, try to build a regex in such a way that there shouldn't be several ways to match a part of your string*? Also, it is `RE2`, not `R2`.

Comment: Well, thank you for the solution, I'm going to test it. However, I hope JS will solve this kind of error in the future. Other languages handle this kind of patterns!

Comment: @JérémyPouyet Not really. Many engines are prone to catastrophic backtracking (and are also more powerful). The engines preventing it are very rare (for example R2). Here's some fun (and classical) lecture on that topic: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: Thanks :) You made my day!